# how to get PHP Smart URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

My website has URL like this

```
domain.com/profile.php?id=your_profile_id
```

now how do i turn it into URL like this

```
domain.com/profile/your_profile_id
```

I tried this thing in .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
```

and it's just helps me to remove .php extension. not the exact thing what i want.
Thanks in advance. have a great day.

Comment: Kindly do add your attempted htaccess rules file in your question, thank you.

Comment: done. you may check it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following rules. Please make sure to place your htaccess file along with your profile.php file.

Also please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/(.*)/?$ $1.php?id=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

what you want to do actually? see if you want to show result as per URL on none existing page / 404 page code on 404 page ,
if you just want URL for statements you can go with simple  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

after fetching URL perform such

```
$myURL = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; // e.g https://www.anything.com/profile.php?id=your_profile_id

$myURL = str_replace("https://","",$myURL );
$myURL = str_replace("http://","",$myURL );
$myURL = str_replace("www.","",$myURL );
$myURL = str_replace(".php","",$myURL );
$myURL = str_replace("?","/",$myURL );
$myURL = str_replace("id=","",$myURL );

output : anything.com/profile/your_profile_id
```